# Definition of final topology

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a set, $\{X_i\}$ a family of topological spaces and for each $i\in I$ there is a map $f_i:X_i\rightarrow X$, then one can define a topology on $X$ which is the finest topology for which the maps $f_i$ are all continuous. Sucha topology is the final topology. According to Bourbaki (and also to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology))) the open sets in $X$ are such that their preimage under each $f_i$ are open sets in $X_i$.

It works fine for the subsets $V\subset Y$ such that

$$\bigcap_{i\in I} f_i(X_i). $$

But I can't understand what happens with the sets $U$ which are not contained in the above intersection. Clearly $f^{-1}_i(U)$ cannot be open in $X_i$, since the operation $f^{-1}_i(U)$ is not defined for at least one index in $I$. A solution would be that $U$ were not open. But then, it may happen that $X$ is not open, which is completely forbidden.

What condition I'm misunderstanding in my above reasoning?

Maybe the subsets $U$ of $X$ such that

$$ U\subseteq \bigcap_{i\in I} f_i(X_i) $$

and $f_i^{-1}(U)$ are open in every space $X_i$ form a basis for the toplogy of $X$ but they **are not** the whole set of open sets (as for example Bourbaki says)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the sentence “Clearly $f^{-1}_i(U)$ cannot be open in $X_i$, since the operation $f^{-1}_i(U)$ is not defined for at least one index in $I$.” For *each* $U\subset Y$ and *each* $i\in I$, it makes sense to talk about $f_i^{-1}(U)$, since it is defined as $\left\{x\in X\,\middle|\,f(x)\in U\right\}$.

Comment: I don't agree with you. Suppose each $X_i=\{x_i\}$ with the trivial topology and that $X_i\cap X_j=\emptyset$. Let $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}$ with the final topology defined with respect to the inclusions. What does $\iota_i^{-1}(\{x_i,x_j\})$ mean? The inverse maps $\iota_i^{-1}$ are defined only in $\operatorname{im}\iota_i$. In this case $\iota_i^{-1}$ is a map from $\{x_i\}\subset X$ onto $\{x_i\}=X_i$.

Comment: For any two sets $X$ and $Y$, any function $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ and any set $U\subset Y$,$$f^{-1}(U)=\left\{x\in X\,\middle|\,f(x)\in U\right\}.$$

Comment: @Dog_69 $i_i^{-1}[\{x_i, x_j\}] = \{x_i\}$ by the definition  I and José gave. They are **not** inverse maps, but inverse images of  a map.

Comment: Okey, Probably  I have mixed the notation $f^{-1}(U)$ with the case in which you have actually the inverse map $f^{-1}$, which is defined from $\operatorname{im}f$ into $X$.  Assuming $f$ ins injective (i.e. $f^{-1}$ is well-defined), do you agree that in the second case $f^{-1}(U)$ does not make sense?

Comment: @Dog_69 Yes, I agree, but that does not matter in this context.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Okey. Thanks for point me my mistake.

Comment: @Dog_69 If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Yes, of course. I was thinking just one moment. I'll mark your answer because you have been the first. But maybe you should include your comment about the meaning of $f^{-1}$ into the answer, don't, you?

Comment: @Dog_69 I agree (and I've edited my answer).

Answer (score 1):

$f^{-1}[U_i]$ is **always** defined, namely as $\{x\in X_i: f_i(x) \in U_i\}$. This might be empty (or even $X_i$) depending on $U_i$.

Example: suppose $f: X \to Y$ is a constant map with value $p \in Y$. Then

$f^{-1}[O]=\emptyset$ when $p\notin O$ and $f^{-1}[O] = X$ when $p\in O$. So open in $X$ always, regardless of the precise topology on $X$.

So the final topology for $f$, is the discrete topology on $Y$: all sets are open.